# Retrieving photo from Azure using Graph API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure

I'm trying to retrieve a profile picture from the Microsoft Azure API. The code below shows how.

```
private getProfilePicture(bearerToken: string, tenantId: string): void {
    let command = CommandHelper.createRestBlobCommand([
        { name: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta'},
        { name: 'me/photo/$value' }
    ]);

    command.Headers.push({ name: 'Authorization', value: 'bearer ' + bearerToken });
    // load the photo from graph api.
    this._gateway.send(command).subscribe(result => {

        let info = result.payload;

        var Base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;
        var temp = 'data:image/bmp;base64,' + Base64.encode('info');
        console.log(temp);

        let action = actions.AuthenticationActions.photoLoaded(info);

        this._store.dispatch(action);
    });
}
```

The problem however is, that when I look at the output it returns :

```
data:image/bmp;base64,W29iamVjdCBCbG9iXQ==
```

Which translates to [object Blob].

My question is how to get the image object here?

Comment: this is the image source without any location. if you want the object right click and save as ...

Comment: headmax, how should that be done in code?

Answer (score 0):

with PHP is much simple in nodejs you have to put this to the function who return req as param and do it like this :

```
app.get('/...', function(req, res){ ...

var base64Data = req.rawBody.replace(/^data:image\/bmp;base64,/, "");

require("fs").writeFile("out.bmp", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```